# Show that $int(A)$ is the union of all open subsets of $A$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$. Show that $int(A)$ is the union of all open subsets of $A$.

We have defined the intererior of $A$, $int(A)$ to be the set of interior points. Furthermore $x \in X$ is an interior point if there is $U \in U_x$ with $U \subset A$. Where $U_x$ is the neighbourhood system of $x$.

> For every point $x_i \in int(A) \ \exists U \in U_x \ : \ U \subset A$. Since $U \in U_x \ \exists V \in T (open) \ : \ x_i \in V_i$ and $V_i \subset U \subset A$. Therefor we can conclude $\cup_i V_i \subset A$.

Now I need help with how I can proceed.

Edit from comment.

$U_x = \{U \in X : U \text{ neighbourhood of } x\in X \}$ A set $U \subset X$ is called a neighbourhood if there is $V \in T$ with $x \in V$ and $V \subset U$.

Comment: How did you define the neighborhood system of $x$? In particular, how did you define the neighborhood of $x$?

Comment: Some authors say that a neighborhood of $x$ is any set that contains some open set $G$ such that $x\in G$. While others define it as any open set that contains $x$. Which of the two are you using?

Comment: I have updated my question including the definitions. @ΘΣΦGenSan

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan I would suspect that the definition is an open neighborhood, but the OP should clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $Y$ be the union of all open subsets of $A$.

- Therefore, $Y\subseteq A$ and $Y$ is open (since the union of arbitrary open sets is open).  Therefore, if $y\in Y$, then $y\in \operatorname{int}(A)$ as we can use $Y$ for $U_y$.
- Suppose $x\in\operatorname{int}(A)$, then $U_x$ is an open subset of $A$ containing $x$, so $U_x$ is in the union defining $Y$.  Therefore, $U_x\subseteq Y$ and so $x\in Y$.

Comment: Nice and clean +1.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in \bigcup_{V\subset A} V$ with $V$ open. Then $x\in U$ for some open subset $U\subset A$. Since $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ contained in $A$, $x$ is an interior point. For the converse, suppose $x$ is an interior point. Then there is a neighborhood $x\in V\subset A$. By definition, this implies the existance of an open $U\subset V$ such that $x\subset U \subset A$. Thus $x\in \bigcup_{V\subset A} V$.